# what could be the challenges of keeping data scattered across multiple database systems(which may be of different types)?

Tags: database, database-design

I have been exploring about databases recently and I want to know about:

1. what could be the challenges a company might have to face when the data is spread across multiple databases which may be of different types?

   One problem that I could think of is the cost of querying across multiple databases and also the verifiability and correctness of the output

   Any more issues?
2. What consideration should be taken and best way to tackle them if we want to merge these data together so that info is not lost?

Answer (score 1):

Issues off the top of my head:

1. Query problems: how do you do Joins between tables in different databases?
2. Multiple SQL dialects - maintenance nightmare
3. Multiple points of failure
4. Consistency of data across multiple databases: small differences in update time can cause queries to fail
5. Your company's Architects are either at war with each other, mad, or both.

No company would willingly end up in a situation like this, although it does happen - point 5 is not unknown!. The usual solution is to have extracts from each database into a single Data Warehouse database which is optimised for reporting, and from which reports must be resilient in the face of inconsistencies (Database A extract failed last night but the rest were OK), and whose users accept that data will only be updated daily (this is usually actually fine).